# Does iterating derivatives always take us to a multiple of the exponential?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function defined everywhere on the real line, such that all of its n-th derivatives are also defined everywhere, in other words, an everywhere smooth function. Suppose further that the sequence of n-th derivatives converges everywhere, at least pointwise, to a limit function $g$. We are not making any assumptions that $g$ itself is differentiable or even continuous. Must $g$ be a multiple of the exponential function $e^x$?